# Shortest way to calculate difference between two numbers?

Tags: c++, math

I'm about to do this in C++ but I have had to do it in several languages, it's a fairly common and simple problem, and this is the last time. I've had enough of coding it as I do, I'm sure there must be a better method, so I'm posting here before I write out the same long winded method in yet another language;

Consider the (<strike>lilies!</strike>) following code;

```
// I want the difference between these two values as a positive integer
int x = 7
int y = 3
int diff;
// This means you have to find the largest number first 
// before making the subtract, to keep the answer positive
if (x>y) { 
     diff = (x-y);
} else if (y>x) {
     diff = (y-x);
} else if (x==y) {
    diff = 0;
}
```

This may sound petty but that seems like a lot to me, just to get the difference between two numbers. Is this in fact a completely reasonable way of doing things and I'm being unnecessarily pedantic, or is my spidey sense tingling with good reason?

Comment: `return std::abs(x-y)`? (using [`abs` from `<cstdlib>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) though C++11 has additional functionality). Pretty much every other language you'd use has a standardized/built-in function that will do the same thing.

Comment: @birryree: `<cmath>` doesn't have `abs`, it has `std::abs`.

Comment: @birryree The `abs` from `<cmath>` is for floats and doubles.  You want the `abs` from `<cstdlib>`

Comment: @RobertCooper Everyone's so fast, even though I changed my comment pretty quickly after realizing I was using the `cstdlib` version and not the `cmath` version!

Comment: The "I have had to do it in several languages," part is unclear. Was this an assignment of some kind?

Comment: @Mr Lister: No, It's just a simple maths problem so it's cropped up for me on several occasions so I thought it time to ensure I was performing this operation as optimal as I could

Comment: Don't preoptimize for stuff like this - it's also more typing and less clear than calling out to functions that have been tuned over years to do exactly what you ask to do.

Comment: asking how to write the code is not pre-optimizing

Comment: @rubenvb The way I interpreted it was that he was doing Rube Goldberg stuff for speed, not for idiomatic purposes. But I guess I might just be reading wrong.

Comment: Even if you don't use one of the `abs` functions, there's no need to treat `x==y` as a special case; it can be folded into either of the other two cases.

Comment: @javano: For the sake of completeness and for those with a _here be dragons_ style of interest, I refer you to the Bit Twiddling Hacks page section: ["Compute the integer absolute value (abs) without branching"](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs).  Once you have your difference apply that code to get the absolute value without resorting to a branch.  That said, I certainly do **not** recommended this approach.  Go with the `std::abs()` approach others have mentioned in their answers, instead.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just get the absolute value of the difference:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int diff = std::abs(x-y);
```

Comment: just don't use that with `float` or `double`

Comment: @Inverse: `std::abs` works perfectly with floats and doubles, you just have to include `<cmath>`. In C it does not though (argument gets converted to int -- probably generating a compiler warning).

Comment: isn't this vulnerable to overflow of the `-` operation? And the undefined behaviour of std::abs(INT_MIN)?

Comment: Let `x=-100, y=100`, then we have `abs(x-y) <=> abs(-200)  <=> 200` but if we swap x and y we have `abs(0) <=> 0` which is a different result. What am I missing? We still have to check which one is larger, right?

Comment: @lucidbrot `abs(y-x)` is `abs(100 - -100)` is `abs(100 + 100)` is `abs(200)` is 200.

Comment: @craq: Indeed; consider x=INT_MIN+100, y=INT_MAX-100.  Fundamentally, the difference between two `int` values is an `unsigned int` quantity.

Comment: just don't use that with `unsigned` types, `std::max(a, b)-std::min(a, b)` is safer

Answer (score 34):

Using the `std::abs()` function is one clear way to do this, as others here have suggested.

But perhaps you are interested in succinctly writing this function without library calls.

In that case

```
diff = x > y ? x - y : y - x;
```

is a short way.

In your comments, you suggested that you are interested in speed. In that case, you may be interested in ways of performing this operation that do not require [branching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science)). [This link](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs) describes some.

Answer (score 13):

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int x = 7;
    int y = 3;
    int diff = std::abs(x-y);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

All the existing answers will overflow on extreme inputs, giving [undefined behaviour](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213). @craq pointed this out in a comment.

If you know that your values will fall within a narrow range, it may be fine to do as the other answers suggest, but to handle extreme inputs (i.e. to robustly handle *any* possible input values), you cannot simply subtract the values then apply the `std::abs` function. As craq rightly pointed out, the subtraction may overflow, causing undefined behaviour (consider `INT_MIN - 1`), and the `std::abs` call may also cause undefined behaviour (consider `std::abs(INT_MIN)`). It's no better to determine the min and max of the pair and to then perform the subtraction.

More generally, a `signed int` is unable to represent the maximum difference between two `signed int` values. The `unsigned int` type should be used for the output value.

I see 3 solutions. I've used the explicitly-sized integer types from `stdint.h` here, to close the door on uncertainties like whether `long` and `int` are the same size and range.

**Solution 1.** The low-level way.

```cpp
// I'm unsure if it matters whether our target platform uses 2's complement,
// due to the way signed-to-unsigned conversions are defined in C and C++:
// >  the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting
// >  one more than the maximum value that can be represented
// >  in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type
uint32_t difference_int32(int32_t i, int32_t j) {
    static_assert(
        (-(int64_t)INT32_MIN) == (int64_t)INT32_MAX + 1,
        "Unexpected numerical limits. This code assumes two's complement."
    );

    // Map the signed values across to the number-line of uint32_t.
    // Preserves the greater-than relation, such that an input of INT32_MIN
    // is mapped to 0, and an input of 0 is mapped to near the middle
    // of the uint32_t number-line.
    // Leverages the wrap-around behaviour of unsigned integer types.

    // It would be more intuitive to set the offset to (uint32_t)(-1 * INT32_MIN)
    // but that multiplication overflows the signed integer type,
    // causing undefined behaviour. We get the right effect subtracting from zero.
    const uint32_t offset = (uint32_t)0 - (uint32_t)(INT32_MIN);
    const uint32_t i_u = (uint32_t)i + offset;
    const uint32_t j_u = (uint32_t)j + offset;

    const uint32_t ret = (i_u > j_u) ? (i_u - j_u) : (j_u - i_u);
    return ret;
}
```

I tried a variation on this using bit-twiddling cleverness taken from [https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax) but modern code-generators seem to generate *worse* code with this variation. (I've removed the `static_assert` and the comments.)

```cpp
uint32_t difference_int32(int32_t i, int32_t j) {
    const uint32_t offset = (uint32_t)0 - (uint32_t)(INT32_MIN);
    const uint32_t i_u = (uint32_t)i + offset;
    const uint32_t j_u = (uint32_t)j + offset;

    // Surprisingly it helps code-gen in MSVC 2019 to manually factor-out
    // the common subexpression. (Even with optimisation /O2)
    const uint32_t t = (i_u ^ j_u) & -(i_u < j_u);
    const uint32_t min = j_u ^ t; // min(i_u, j_u)
    const uint32_t max = i_u ^ t; // max(i_u, j_u)
    const uint32_t ret = max - min;
    return ret;
}
```

**Solution 2.** The easy way. Avoid overflow by doing the work using a wider signed integer type. This approach can't be used if the input signed integer type is the largest signed integer type available.

```cpp
uint32_t difference_int32(int32_t i, int32_t j) {
    return (uint32_t)std::abs((int64_t)i - (int64_t)j);
}
```

**Solution 3.** The laborious way. Use flow-control to work through the different cases. Likely to be less efficient.

```cpp
uint32_t difference_int32(int32_t i, int32_t j)
{   // This static assert should pass even on 1's complement.
    // It's just about impossible that int32_t could ever be capable of representing
    // *more* values than can uint32_t.
    // Recall that in 2's complement it's the same number, but in 1's complement,
    // uint32_t can represent one more value than can int32_t.
    static_assert( // Must use int64_t to subtract negative number from INT32_MAX
        ((int64_t)INT32_MAX - (int64_t)INT32_MIN) <= (int64_t)UINT32_MAX,
        "Unexpected numerical limits. Unable to represent greatest possible difference."
    );

    uint32_t ret;
    if (i == j) {
        ret = 0;
    } else {

        if (j > i) { // Swap them so that i > j
            const int32_t i_orig = i;
            i = j;
            j = i_orig;
        } // We may now safely assume i > j

        uint32_t magnitude_of_greater; // The magnitude, i.e. abs()
        bool     greater_is_negative; // Zero is of course non-negative
        uint32_t magnitude_of_lesser;
        bool     lesser_is_negative;

        if (i >= 0) {
            magnitude_of_greater = i;
            greater_is_negative = false;
        } else { // Here we know 'lesser' is also negative, but we'll keep it simple
            // magnitude_of_greater = -i; // DANGEROUS, overflows if i == INT32_MIN.
            magnitude_of_greater = (uint32_t)0 - (uint32_t)i;
            greater_is_negative = true;
        }

        if (j >= 0) {
            magnitude_of_lesser = j;
            lesser_is_negative = false;
        } else {
            // magnitude_of_lesser = -j; // DANGEROUS, overflows if i == INT32_MIN.
            magnitude_of_lesser = (uint32_t)0 - (uint32_t)j;
            lesser_is_negative = true;
        }

        // Finally compute the difference between lesser and greater
        if (!greater_is_negative && !lesser_is_negative) {
            ret = magnitude_of_greater - magnitude_of_lesser;
        } else if (greater_is_negative && lesser_is_negative) {
            ret = magnitude_of_lesser - magnitude_of_greater;
        } else { // One negative, one non-negative. Difference is sum of the magnitudes.
            // This will never overflow.
            ret = magnitude_of_lesser + magnitude_of_greater;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on what you mean by shortest. The fastet runtime, the fastest compilation, the least amount of lines, the least amount of memory. I'll assume you mean runtime.

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::max/min   
int diff = std::max(x,y)-std::min(x,y);
```

This does two comparisons and one operation (this one is unavoidable but could be optimized through certain bitwise operations with specific cases, compiler might actually do this for you though). Also if the compiler is smart enough it could do only one comparison and save the result for the other comparison. E.g if X>Y then you know from the first comparison that Y < X but I'm not sure if compilers take advantage of this.

Comment: this will *still work* even if someone changes the type of `x`, `y` to `unsigned`.